# Dagger new Api. But can't to implement runtime scope with singleton scope

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

My scope:

```
@Scope
@Retention
annotation class ActivityScope
```

AppModule:

```
 @Module(includes = [ActivityModule::class])
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
        return application
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideDataManager(appDataManager: AppDataManager): DataManager {
        return appDataManager
    }


}
```

UsecaseActivityModule :

```
@Module
    class UsecaseActivityModule {

        @Provides
        @RegisterActivityScope
        fun provideUsecase(appDataManager: AppDataManager): UseCase =
            UseCase(appDataManager)

    }


@Module
internal abstract class ActivityModule {


    @ContributesAndroidInjector(
        modules = [
            UsecaseActivityModule::class

        ]
    )
    internal abstract fun contributeUsecaseActivity(): UsecaseActivity

}
```

Issue is I can not provide this:

```
@Provides
        @Singleton
        fun provideContext(application: Application): Context {
            return application
        }
```

got error

> error: (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:   @Subcomponent(
>
> ```
>  bla bla bla ...
> ```
>
> AppComponent.java:6: error: com.example.di.AppComponent scoped with 
>   @Singleton may not reference bindings with different 
>   scopes:
>   @dagger.Component(modules = {dagger.android.AndroidInjectionModule.class,
>   com.example.di.ActivityModule.class, com.example.di.AppModule.class})

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did not specify scope in parent module with @RegisterActivityScope.

```
    @Module
    internal abstract class ActivityModule {

        @RegisterActivityScope // <-- just need add this
        @ContributesAndroidInjector(
            modules = [
                UsecaseActivityModule::class

            ]
        )
        internal abstract fun contributeUsecaseActivity(): UsecaseActivity

    }
```